# how to prevent automatic answer of incoming call

Tags: sinch

i am following this Sinch example to design an app to app calling app: http://www.hnwatcher.com/r/1345925/Android-Use-the-Sinch-SDK-to-build-a-free-calling-app-in-30-mins and i have downloaded the sample app at github.
Everything is working fine except that the incoming call is being answered automatically. I would like the call be answered after the receiver clicks a button. How can i achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you app is notified of an incoming call then the following delegate method is called (I have copied this straight from the Sinch app to app call [tutorial](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-simple-voice-app-tutorial/)):

```
- (void)client:(id<SINCallClient>)client didReceiveIncomingCall:(id<SINCall>)call {
    // For now we are just going to answer calls, 
    // in a normal app you would show in incoming call screen
    call.delegate = self;
    _call = call;
    [_call answer];
}
```

In this tutorial the call is meant to be answered straight away so we call

```
[_call answer];
```

to answer it.

To make the call answer at the push of a button you need simply move the above line of code out of this delegate method into a button action and it will work.

```
- (IBAction)answerButtonPressed: (UIButton *)button {
    [_call answer];
}
```

Adding the above will mean that when a call comes in it won't be immediately answered and when you click the button the call will be connected.

Note: Don't forget to keep a pointer to the incoming call so that you answer the call as it is coming in. We can see this happening in the receive call method:

```
_call = call;
```